# Fetch result to a json array PDO

Tags: php, json, pdo

im using `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` of the PDO class for fetching my results, then i take the result and run it through `json_encode($results)` which results in :

```
{ "0" : { "key" : "value" }, "1" : { "key" : "value" } }
```

But i was expecting :

```
 [ { "key" : "value" },{ "key" : "value" } ]
```

as Json array is more natural and reasonable then Json object in my case.

How would you go about either converting the json object to json array, or get the json array in the first place by using some other fetch style or any other suggestion?

Comment: Are you using the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` option? Don't do that if you want an ordinary array.

Comment: Are you doing any further processing on the result before you encode it? I would expect an array as well but if you for example delete an element, it would not be a valid javascript array any more.

Comment: @Barmar nope not using that explicitly

Comment: @jeroen no, i get those results and put them to json directly

Comment: Then I can't think of any reason why this is happening. What does `var_dump($results)` show?

Comment: You need to post the code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it heppened because i had some other type values in that json, something like :

`{ "0" : { "key" : "value" }, "1" : { "key" : "value" } , "key" : [ { "key" : "value" } ]}`

I just introduced a key for the array and it worked :

`{ "key" : [{ "key" : "value" },{ "key" : "value" }] , "key" : [ { "key" : "value" } ]}`